# No blocking Ethernet capture

Tags: go, pcap, gopacket

I use this code to capture Ehternet packet:

```
var snapshotLen int32 = 102400
var promiscuous bool = true
var timeout time.Duration = 1 * time.Second
var handle *pcap.Handle
handle, err = pcap.OpenLive(device, snapshotLen, promiscuous, timeout)
err = handle.SetBPFFilter(filter)

packetSource := gopacket.NewPacketSource(handle, handle.LinkType())
for packet := range packetSource.Packets() {

}
```

Problem is packetSource.Packets() is blocking: if no packet received, there is an infinite loop. How can I do to set a timeout?

Comment: A nitpick: a blocking iteration of a loop and an infinite loop are different concepts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the docs](https://godoc.org/github.com/google/gopacket#PacketSource.Packets):

> `func (p *PacketSource) Packets() chan Packet`
>
> Packets returns a channel of packets, allowing easy iterating over
> packets. Packets will be asynchronously read in from the underlying
> PacketDataSource and written to the returned channel. If the
> underlying `PacketDataSource` returns an `io.EOF` error, the channel will
> be closed. If any other error is encountered, it is ignored.
>
> ```golang
> for packet := range packetSource.Packets() {   handlePacket(packet) 
> // Do something with each packet. }
> ```
>
> If called more than once, returns the same channel.

So, since `gopacket.PacketSource.Packets()` returns a channel, you can employ the usual tactic of `select`ing on two channels—an operation on one of which is controlled by a timeout.

In the simplest case, something like this would do:

```golang
timer := time.NewTicker(2 * time.Second)
defer timer.Stop()

src := gopacket.NewPacketSource(handle, handle.LinkType())
for {
    select {
        case pkt := <- src.Packets():
            // process a packet in pkt
        case <- timer.C:
            // timed out waiting for 2 seconds
    }
}
```

Depending on the exact use case, the second channel can come from another source—such as a [context](https://blog.golang.org/context).

Comment: I thank you, it operates.

I replaced : "case <- timer.C:" by "case <-time.After(time.Second * time.Duration(custTimeout)):"

Comment: @ipStack, sorry, I meant `time.NewTicker`, of course. Updated.